# I'm gettin Null Reference in Unity and don't know why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, null

Here is the error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle.CheckReadAndThrow (Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle handle) (at <13e6546058e340ada820e34dce3b245e>:0)
> Unity.Collections.NativeList`1[T].get_Length () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collections@1.2.4/Unity.Collections/NativeList.cs:227)
> Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkDriver+Concurrent.BeginSend (Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkPipeline pipe, Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkConnection id, Unity.Networking.Transport.DataStreamWriter& writer, System.Int32 requiredPayloadSize) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.transport@1.1.0/Runtime/NetworkDriver.cs:177)
> Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkDriver.BeginSend (Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkConnection id, Unity.Networking.Transport.DataStreamWriter& writer, System.Int32 requiredPayloadSize) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.transport@1.1.0/Runtime/NetworkDriver.cs:1210)
> Server.SendToClient (Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkConnection connection, NetMessage msg) (at Assets/Scripts/Net/Server.cs:196)
> Chessboard.OnWelcomeServer (NetMessage msg, Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkConnection cnn) (at Assets/Scripts/Chessboard.cs:774)
> NetWelcome.ReceivedOnServer (Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkConnection cnn) (at Assets/Scripts/Net/NetMessage/NetWelcome.cs:32)
> NetUtility.OnData (Unity.Networking.Transport.DataStreamReader stream, Unity.Networking.Transport.NetworkConnection cnn, Server server) (at Assets/Scripts/Net/NetUtility.cs:32)
> Server.UpdateMessagePump () (at Assets/Scripts/Net/Server.cs:133)
> Server.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Net/Server.cs:121)

Code:

```
using Unity.Collections;
using System;
using Unity.Networking.Transport;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string GetLocalIpAddress()
    {
            UnicastIPAddressInformation mostSuitableIp = null;

            var networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (var network in networkInterfaces)
            {
                if (network.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up)
                    continue;

                var properties = network.GetIPProperties();

                if (properties.GatewayAddresses.Count == 0)
                    continue;

                foreach (var address in properties.UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (address.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        continue;

                    if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(address.Address))
                        continue;

                    if (!address.IsDnsEligible)
                    {
                        if (mostSuitableIp == null)
                            mostSuitableIp = address;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // The best IP is the IP got from DHCP server
                    if (address.PrefixOrigin != PrefixOrigin.Dhcp)
                    {
                        if (mostSuitableIp == null || !mostSuitableIp.IsDnsEligible)
                            mostSuitableIp = address;
                        continue;
                    }

                return address.Address.ToString();
                }
            }

        return mostSuitableIp != null
            ? mostSuitableIp.Address.ToString()
            : "";
    }

    #region Singeton implementation
    public static Server Instance { set; get; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    #endregion

    public NetworkDriver driver;
    private NativeList<NetworkConnection> connections;

    private bool isLocal = false;
    private bool isActive = false;
    private const float keepAliveTickRate = 20.0f;
    private float lastKeepAlive;

    public Action connectionDropped;

    // Methods
    public void Init(ushort port, bool localGame)
    {
        isLocal = localGame;
        driver = NetworkDriver.Create();
        NetworkEndPoint endPoint = NetworkEndPoint.Parse(GetLocalIpAddress(), port);
        Debug.Log("TEST Local: " + endPoint.Address);
        // endPoint.Port = port;
        if (driver.Bind(endPoint) != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to bind op port" + endPoint.Port);
        }
        else
        {
            driver.Listen();
            Debug.Log("Currently listening on port" + endPoint.Port);
        }

        connections = new NativeList<NetworkConnection>(2, Allocator.Persistent);
        isActive = true;
    }
    public void Shutdown()
    {
        if (isActive)
        {
            driver.Dispose();
            connections.Dispose();
            isActive = false;
        }
    }
    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        Shutdown();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (!isActive)
            return;
        KeepAlive();


        driver.ScheduleUpdate().Complete();
        CleanupConnections();
        AcceptNewConnection();
        UpdateMessagePump();
    }
    private void UpdateMessagePump()
    {
        DataStreamReader stream;
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.Length; i++)
        {
            NetworkEvent.Type cmd;
            while ((cmd = driver.PopEventForConnection(connections[i], out stream)) != NetworkEvent.Type.Empty)
            {
                if (cmd == NetworkEvent.Type.Data)
                {
                    NetUtility.OnData(stream, connections[i], this);
                }
                else if (cmd == NetworkEvent.Type.Disconnect)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Client disconnected from server");
                    connections[i] = default(NetworkConnection);
                    connectionDropped?.Invoke();
                    Shutdown(); // This is only if it is locah Host
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Server specific
    private void KeepAlive()
    {
        if((Time.time - lastKeepAlive) > keepAliveTickRate)
        {
            lastKeepAlive = Time.time;
            Broadcast(new NetKeepAlive());
        }
    }
    private void CleanupConnections()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!connections[i].IsCreated)
            {
                connections.RemoveAtSwapBack(i);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
    private void AcceptNewConnection()
    {
        NetworkConnection c;
        // Accept new connections
        if (isLocal == true)
        {
            if (connections.Length == 0)
            {
                while ((c = driver.Accept()) != default(NetworkConnection))
                {
                    connections.Add(c);
                    Debug.Log("New connection Added");
                }
            }
        }
        else if(isLocal == false)
        {   
            if(connections.Length <= 1)
            {
                while ((c = driver.Accept()) != default(NetworkConnection))
                {
                    connections.Add(c);
                    Debug.Log("New connection Added");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void SendToClient(NetworkConnection connection, NetMessage msg)
    {
        DataStreamWriter writer;
        driver.BeginSend(connection, out writer);
        msg.Serialize(ref writer);
        driver.EndSend(writer);
    }
    public void Broadcast(NetMessage msg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.Length; i++)
            if (connections[i].IsCreated)
            {
            //    Debug.Log($"Sending {msg.Code} to : {connections[1].InternalId}");
                SendToClient(connections[i], msg);
            }
    }
}
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: That error message is telling you that the Null Refrence is comming from the `  UpdateMessagePump();` function in the update loop of the script you have provided. We'd need to see that to help you any more

Comment: I think cleanupconnection has bug.  If a connection never completes it doesn't get removed.  So the number of connections is 1 but the connection is null.  Then UpdateMessagePump is called.  Connection count is one but connection[0] is null.

Comment: @jdweng Do you know how i can fix it?

Comment: Add at beginning of for loop : if(connections[i] == null) continue;

Comment: @jdweng i but in in the for loop and evey thing else in a else loop but i get the same error

Comment: Continue will skip everything in the for loop and go to next higher value of i.

Comment: @jdweng i get basic the same error
but it is on line 138 which is the same code.
and i it does not trigeer because when i but a debug in the i don't get it in the conssole

Comment: When you are reading a file using while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) there are two different checks being performed.  The code is not testing that line equals null.  It is testing that the reader stream is not null.  In you case cmd does not equal NetworkEvent.Type.Disconnect.  You want to test that the stream equals NetworkEvent.Type.Disconnect

Comment: @jdweng what do i need to do to fix it
i added this affter the while                    
 if(cmd == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

Comment: You want to test "stream".  I think you have a Network Stream.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng I'm using unity transport network so how do i test is?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Yesterday I read a few articles on how to determine when a network stream connection disconnects.  Some people said you can't, and other said you need to put in a try/catch so you can continue.  I would add the try/catch so you can continue.